# Close previous popup on another button click and open new popup with new data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a popup in ReactJs and there are multiple categories on the home page that opens the same popup component. I want to open a new popup if a different category is selected and the previous popup should be closed but a new popup opens over others every time I click on the new category.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a state let's call it `selectedPopup` that you need to initialize to `""`, then poup is shown only when `selectedPopup` is `!== ""`.
when you click on a category you just `setSelectedPopup("category name")` that will show the popup and when you click to close it you do `setSelectedPopup("")`.
if the user selects the same category then `selectedPopup` is not updated so the correspondent popup is already shown.

Comment: still showing old popup here is the componet code snippets- const handleCategoryClick = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    setShowPopup(!showPopup);
    setSelectedPopup(category);
  };

Comment: @AjayJha would you provide an example?

Comment: const callbackFunction = () => {
    setShowPopup(false);
    setSelectedPopup("");
  }

Comment: return (
    <>
    { selectedPopup !== "" && showPopup && <PopupBox category={category} callbackFunction = {callbackFunction}/>}
      <div className='category-box' role='button' onClick={handleCategoryClick} >
        <h1 style={{ color: '#203b8a', fontSize: '24px', fontWeight: 'bold', margin: '0'}}>{capitalizedCategory}</h1>
        <p style={{ color: '#6c21a8', fontSize: '14px', margin: '0' }}>Unlimited Jokes On {capitalizedCategory}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );

Comment: you just use `selectedPopup` instead of `showPopup`

Comment: still showing old popups

Comment: get rid of `showPopup` state, `selectedPopup` will take its place

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254386/discussion-between-hatana-and-ajay-jha).